# tree in tabview lazy loading

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabview

I have an tabView with tree.
Whenever I load a tab, primefaces initial all Tabs.
It seems as dynamic="true" does not work

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true" cache="true">

<p:tab id="tab1" title="1">
</p:tab>

<p:tab id="tab2" title="2">
</p:tab>

<p:tab id="tab3" title="3">
</p:tab>

<p:tab id="tab4" title="content">
   <p:tree value="#{myBean.tree}" var="node" id="tree" animate="true" dynamic="true">
      <p:treeNode>
        stuff
      </p:treeNode>
   </p:tree>
</p:tab>

<p:tab id="tab5" title="5">
</p:tab>

</p:tabView>
```

Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
@Named(value = "myBean")
public class MyBean implements Serializable
{

    private Integer activeTab;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3915849796901858147L;

    public MyBean()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Integer getActiveTab()
    {
        return activeTab;
    }

    public void setActiveTab(final Integer tab)
    {
        this.activeTab = tab;
    }


    public TreeNode getTree()
    {
       System.out.println("TREE");
    }
}
```

Once a tab is clicked, the method getTree is called five times
Click on Tab 1:

```
Console
TREE
TREE
TREE
TREE
TREE
```

Click on Tab 2:

```
Console
TREE
TREE
TREE
TREE
TREE
```

IF i replaced `<p:tree>` witn `<h:outputText>` its works as it should.

Any ideas?

primefaces 3.5
glassfish 3.1.2

Comment: Do you mean, when you have outputText instead of p:tree, the tabs are loaded dynamically?

Comment: yes, the tabs loaded dynamically